# Rails where clause match integer with the array

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an issue in finding the correct records from the database. This is my query:

```
@interested_individual = Profile.where('category_id = ?', @event.interests).all
```

Where `category_id` is the column in the profiles table what holds the integer value and `@event.interests` returns an array that is ["1", "2", "3"]

What I want here is to fetch all the profiles where its `category_id` is present in the `@event.interests` array.
Please let me know the solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to manually write the binding with `?` and all.

Try this:

```
@interested_individual = Profile.where(category_id: @event.interests).all
```

Active Record will then turn that into `category_id IN (?)` for you if you pass in an array.

Answer (score 2):

This query will translate to `category_id IN [interest_ids...]`

```
Profile.where(category_id: @event.interests).all
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close. Use `IN`.

```
@interested_individual = Profile.where('category_id IN (?)', @event.interests).all
```

But, I would suggest [find](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) you here, if you are only wanted to get collection of all `Profile` records :

```
@interested_individual = Profile.find(@event.interests)
```